# onCreate() and onStarCommand() methods not being called

Tags: java, android

I have a service that uses the following code:

```
package com.ritvik.weaselyclock;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.ritvik.utils.JSONUtils;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public final static String CLOCK_ANG = "com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.CLOCKANG";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Handler mHandler;
    static final String TAG = "Receive Message Activity";


    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("44937255078");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        return startId; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // Post notification of received message.
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                handleMessage(extras.getString("message"));
            } 
        }
    }
    public void handleMessage(final String msg) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject JSON = null;
                String type = "";
                try {
                    JSON = new JSONObject(msg);
                    type = JSON.getString("type");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (type.equals("ru_101")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, MainActivity.class));
                    Toast.makeText(GcmIntentService.this, "Registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if (type.equals("ru_002")) {
                    Toast.makeText(GcmIntentService.this, "Registration successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if (type.equals("ru_301")) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(GcmIntentService.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
                    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    try {
                        resultIntent.putExtra("com.ritvik.weaselyclock.phone", JSON.getString("phone_number"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
                    // started Activity.
                    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
                    // your application to the Home screen.
                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(GcmIntentService.this);
                    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
                    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                    0,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                                    );
                    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_good, "Accept", resultPendingIntent);
                    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_discard, "Reject", resultPendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    int mId = 001;
                    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
                }
                else if (  type.equals("ru_101") || type.equals("ru_102") 
                        || type.equals("ru_103") || type.equals("ru_201") 
                        || type.equals("ru_202") || type.equals("ru_203") 
                        || type.equals("ru_204") || type.equals("ru_205") 
                        || type.equals("ru_206") || type.equals("ru_207") 
                        || type.equals("ru_208") || type.equals("ru_209") 
                        || type.equals("ru_210") || type.equals("ru_211") 
                        || type.equals("jr_201") || type.equals("jr_202")
                        || type.equals("jr_203") || type.equals("jr_204")
                        || type.equals("jr_205") || type.equals("jr_206")
                        || type.equals("jr_207") || type.equals("jr_208")
                        || type.equals("jr_209") || type.equals("id_201")
                        || type.equals("id_202") || type.equals("id_203")
                        || type.equals("id_204") || type.equals("id_205")
                        || type.equals("id_206") || type.equals("id_207")
                        || type.equals("id_208") || type.equals("sm_201")
                        || type.equals("sm_202") || type.equals("sm_203")
                        || type.equals("sm_204") || type.equals("sm_205")
                        || type.equals("sm_206") || type.equals("sm_207")
                        || type.equals("sm_208") || type.equals("sm_209")
                        || type.equals("sm_210")) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("Server error:", JSON.getString("error"));
                        Toast.makeText(GcmIntentService.this, "Server error: " + JSON.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                else if (type.equals("jr_101") || type.equals("jr_102")) {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(GcmIntentService.this, JSON.getString("action"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                else if (type.equals("jr_301") || type.equals("jr_302")) {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(GcmIntentService.this, "You have been " + JSON.getString("action") + "by group" + JSON.getString("group") , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                else if (type.equals("id_101")) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray members = JSON.getJSONArray("members");
                        JSONUtils.writeJSON("com.ritvik.weaselyclock.MEMBERS", GcmIntentService.this, members, "members");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For some reason, according to the debugger, the onStartCommand() method is never being called. I'd tried to use onCreate(), but that wasn't being called either. The app then crashes with the following LogCat output:

```
04-28 08:25:35.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11113): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-775
04-28 08:25:35.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11113): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 08:25:35.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11113):    at com.ritvik.weaselyclock.GcmIntentService.handleMessage(GcmIntentService.java:69)
04-28 08:25:35.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11113):    at com.ritvik.utils.HTTPUtils$1.run(HTTPUtils.java:48)
04-28 08:25:35.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11113):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

EDIT: the issue isn't so much that the methods aren't being called as that the handler is not being initialized properly.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you must check string is empty or not before passing it to JSon constructor

Comment: what line is `at com.ritvik.weaselyclock.GcmIntentService.handleMessage(GcmIntentService.java:69)` in the code, the sniplet does not show line numbers.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk: `mHandler.post(new Runnable() {`.

Comment: @Nilesh I will add that code, but that doesn't seem to be the problem... the exception is coming from `mHandler.post(new Runnable() {`

Comment: Can you post code how do you start Service? I think you're binding it instead of starting (using bindService instead of startService). In this case onStartCommand won't be called

Comment: Oh, wait... I'm only calling that method, not actually starting the service.